# Why is $G \circ F$ not invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inverse

I have two simple linear maps:

$F:\mathbb{R_{≤ 3}[x]} \to \mathbb{R^{2,2}} \ ; \ ax^3+bx^2+cx+d \to 
\left[       \begin{array}{cc}       c-d& b+c  \\       a-c & b  \\        \end{array}\right],$

$G:\mathbb{R^{2,2}} \to \mathbb{R_{≤ 1}[x]} \ ;\left[       \begin{array}{cc}       a& b  \\       c & d  \\        \end{array}\right] \to \ (a+b+2c)x-2d $.

I have proven that $F$ is invertible:

$\begin{pmatrix}r&s\\ t&u\end{pmatrix}=:\begin{pmatrix}c-d&b+c\\ a-c&b\end{pmatrix}$

So we get: $a = s + t -u$, $b = u$, $c = s - u$ and $d = s-r-u$

$F^{-1}\left(\begin{pmatrix}r&s\\ t&u\end{pmatrix}\right)=\left(s+t-u\right)x^3+ux^2+\left(s-u\right)x+\left(s-r-u\right)$

> My question is, why aren't $G$ and $G \circ F$ invertible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because $G$ and $G\circ F$ are linear maps from a $4$-dimensional space into a $2$-dimensional space. Such a map is never injective (it follows from the rank-nullity theorem, for instance), and therefore it is never an isomorphism.